# Symfony 5 doc recommendation for twig installs it then removes it

Tags: symfony, composer-php, twig

I'm going through a new test Symfony 5 install right now, and I'm on this section of the docs:

https://symfony.com/doc/5.4/page_creation.html#rendering-a-template

I ran `composer require twig`, and it says it's installing it, then when composer runs 'Unpacking Symfony packs', it then states "Removing symfony/twig-pack (v1.0.1)"...

I notice later in my VCS that nothing changed in composer.json and composer.lock, so the command at least didn't change any non-gitignored files. I notice `twig/twig` is specified as a dependency for packages all over composer.lock, so maybe it's just using one of those...? I'm a little confused at this point.

So my questions are: **Why did it install it if it's already in composer.lock, and why then did it remove it?** Am I reading the output wrong?

I think some of the output is from Symfony's composer.json "scripts" section, which was pre-written by running:

```
composer create-project symfony/skeleton:"^5.4" my_project_directory
cd my_project_directory
composer require webapp
```

from this page: https://symfony.com/doc/5.4/setup.html#creating-symfony-applications

Relevant pre-existing auto-generated composer.json specs:

```
"symfony/framework-bundle": "5.4.*",
"symfony/twig-bundle": "5.4.*",
"twig/extra-bundle": "^2.12|^3.0",
"twig/twig": "^2.12|^3.0"
```

Here's my composer output... sorry for the long post, should be easy to pick out relevant points anyway:

```
symfony-5 % composer require twig
Using version ^1.0 for symfony/twig-pack
./composer.json has been updated
Running composer update symfony/twig-pack
Loading composer repositories with package information
Info from https://repo.packagist.org: #StandWithUkraine
Updating dependencies
Lock file operations: 1 install, 0 updates, 0 removals
  - Locking symfony/twig-pack (v1.0.1)
Writing lock file
Installing dependencies from lock file (including require-dev)
Package operations: 1 install, 0 updates, 0 removals
  - Installing symfony/twig-pack (v1.0.1): Extracting archive
Generating optimized autoload files
115 packages you are using are looking for funding.
Use the `composer fund` command to find out more!

Run composer recipes at any time to see the status of your Symfony recipes.

Unpacking Symfony packs
  - Unpacked symfony/twig-pack
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Nothing to modify in lock file
Installing dependencies from lock file (including require-dev)
Package operations: 0 installs, 0 updates, 1 removal
  - Removing symfony/twig-pack (v1.0.1)
Generating optimized autoload files
114 packages you are using are looking for funding.
Use the `composer fund` command to find out more!

Run composer recipes at any time to see the status of your Symfony recipes.

Executing script cache:clear [OK]
Executing script assets:install public [OK]

No security vulnerability advisories found

No security vulnerability advisories found
```

Also, I'm scratching my chin on why "No security vulnerability advisories found" is being outputted twice...

Comment: Could you add your `composer.json` so we can see what's going on there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That doc page is just telling you how twig is installed. The beginning of each section of the docs will start out by telling you how the particular subject component is installed. That is because it is common for developers to create their projects with the bare minimum dependencies, and add more only as needed. The components can also be used 'stand-alone' without the Symfony framework. Either way, the logical first step for using twig templates is to make sure you have twig installed, so they show you how to do that first.

You already have it installed if you ran `composer require webapp` or you created project with `symfony new my_project_directory --version=5.4 --webapp`. The `--webapp` option will add common dependencies for traditional web applications including twig.

So, by running `composer require twig` with flex it will run a recipe that installs `symfony/twig-pack` then adds it's required packages to your required packages if you don't already have them. Then `symfony/twig-pack` is no longer needed so it gets removed.
These packs like `symfony/twig-pack` only require additional packages. You already have the packages installed so no other actions are needed.

Comment: My initial post was not entirely correct (and still may not be), I have edited my answer.

Comment: Arleigh explained it well enough. I'll just add that `composer require twig` actually is an [alias for twig-pack](https://symfony.com/doc/current/quick_tour/flex_recipes.html#flex-recipes-and-aliases). [Twig pack](https://packagist.org/packages/symfony/twig-pack) installs three packages: symfony/twig-bundle, twig/twig and twig/extra-bundle. Once the pack is installed, the pack itself is removed and the other packages are left. As Arleigh explained, you probably have the three packages already, so in the end nothing was changed.